# cache lookup decisions is virtual or physical address based

Tags: system, cpu, cpu-cache, opencpu

Whether TLB lookups are done on virtual addresses or physical addresses? 
When TLB hit then it means virtual address to physical pfn is residing in cache memory or data is residing in cache memory

Please provide some pointers where to get detail understanding of cache memory

Answer (score 2):

The TLB contains a mapping between virtual and physical addresses only. A TLB hit means that a given virtual address has a physical address mapping in the TLB. It has nothing to do with whether the data at that memory location is in the cache or not.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, need to confirm how the mapping is managed by TLB, Any good reference which shows detailed insight of cache layer.